# Remove specific values from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, logic

I have two `NSArray`s, `array1` and `array2`.

If `array1` has values of `7`,`8`,`9`,`10` and `array2` has values of `7`,`9`,`10`; how would I remove only the variables that do not exist within `array2`.

So `array1` would go from `7`,`8`,`9`,`10` - to `7`,`9`,`10`.

Comment: We assume that the objects are `NSNumber`s in both arrays?

Comment: And are the arrays mutable (`removeObjectsInArray:`)?

Comment: Do you really need arrays? I mean do you have use for the index at all? If not, then have a look for NSSet. NSSet are collections like NSArray which you can iterate etc. but they don't have indexes and are not sorted (but can be transformed to sorted arrays if needed). But the provide you with all of these set methods like unions and intersects, what you currently need.

Comment: Thanks Hermann! I'll definitely look into them.

Comment: They are NSString's, sorry.

Comment: Easily 5 different ways to do this.  Most straight-forward is to iterate through the first array and search the second for each element of the first.  N-squared, but not a problem if your arrays are of modest size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NSMutableSet intersectSet:` method to find the intersection of both arrays.

E.g. something like:

```
NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:firstArray];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:secondArray]];

NSArray *intersectionArray = [intersection allObjects];
```

Comment: This code does not seem to work for me.

        NSArray *allYearArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"7", @"9", @"11" @"12", nil];
        NSArray *userYearArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"7", @"9", @"12", nil];
        

        NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:allYearArray];
        [intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:userYearArray]];
        
        NSArray *intersectionArray = [intersection allObjects];
        
        NSLog(@"intersectionArray: %@", intersectionArray);

This returns:

7, 9

Comment: In this code you forgot a comma in `@"11" @"12"`, if you add the comma it should work.

Comment: Geez, that's embarrassing., it works now. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Yeah, in (Objective-)C, adjacent string literals are concatinated.

Comment: Definitely keep an eye out for it in the future!